# Android studio Gradle :: dependencies {compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.0' } fails compilation

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I recently switched to android studio for development.
I had created project with **minsdk,targetsdk and compile with sdk as Google Api Level 8.**

The project compilation fails due to following code in build.gradle file.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.0'
}
```

Can anyone tell why this is hapenning?

My whole build.gradle is posted below.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 8
    buildToolsVersion "18.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 8
    }
}

dependencies {
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.0'
    }
```

Below is the screenshot
[image]

Comment: could u post the whole build.gradle ?

Comment: posted the build.gradle in the question.

Comment: Have you updated Android Support Repository and
Android Support Library in your SDK Manager?

Comment: How to do this? I don't know? Please elaborate.

Comment: for SDK Manager : Tools -> Android -> SDK Manager , try to update and then run ./gradlew clean && build --info (this will clean and rebuild) , if you still get error please post the detailed one in here

Comment: I had updated the android sdk using SDK Manager Still getting the issue.I had attached screenshot of android studio.

Comment: can you check your gradle version? You can see it in /gradle/gradle-wrapper.properties inside your project.

Comment: I am using gradle version 1.7

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't compile against any API *below* 11 and use the AppCompat library. It references the Holo style and the compiler will have no way to resolve those symbols if you're building against an old version.

Get rid of the problem by building against API level 18. This won't break the app for older devices, but you will need to heed the lint API warnings to ensure compatibility. You may have to re-sync the IDE with the gradle files by clicking the gradle icon on the menu bar.

Answer (score 2):

Open "Android SDK Manager"

Install "Extra/Android Support Repository"